# PDO database connection whitespace throws error!

Tags: mysql, pdo

Ok so I am one for spacing out my code, I find it easier to read, edit and understand. The current way to connect to mysql with PDO is as follows on php.net;

```
$dbc=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='table', 'root', 'password');
```

I like my eligibilty so I edited like this adding whitespace;

```
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = 'table', 'root', 'password');
```

Doing so throws an error, it is not so much as a problem as it doesn't concern me that much at all, but I thought php does not consider whitespace? So why the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO DSN syntax doesn't allow to add spaces in any place you want.

This syntax has nothing to do with regular php syntax rules, just because it is a string with DSN and not php.